# Unique List Items

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

So I know there are unique entry options for individual columns but I wanted to know if there is a way to enforce Unique items? Looking below at the photo I provided. If rather enforcing say the multiples of a single column like column one's RX01121 I wanted to enforce the uniqueness of the first row as a whole. So The row with that contains

```
RX01121 | 6192 | 0010 | AR205610
```

Doesn't appear multiple times. For example is we have:

```
RX01121 | 6192 | 0010 | AR205610
```

This would fail to be added to this list because a copy of it already exists on the list. However if you replaced 6192 with 6191 that would be added to the list and would be counted as its own unique row.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that here you have the two only solutions for having several columns as unique in a SharePoint list,

- client-side scripting or
- event receiver when adding and modifying.

Apart from that, there is no *out-of-the-box* solution to reach that functionality.

Here you have the [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee536168(v=office.14)) with the specifications for it. Anyway, I also found another similar or exact question as to the one you have with the correct answer, [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128677/unique-validation-on-calculated-column).

Comment: So in the first column mark Unique values as true?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. Try it and let me know.

Comment: "This field contains duplicate values. Remove all duplicate values and try the operation again." Is what I get without removing any entries.

Comment: So you have to change the values for those rows in order to have unique values on each row. Then, try to set the property to true again.

Comment: Alright I did that but now I can't upload anything that would share the same 1st column which many items of the data all share

Comment: Sorry but there is something I don't understand though. What do you mean with "to enforce the uniqueness of the first row"? Could you edit the question and provide the desired result?

Comment: I mean each Row is unique rather than individual columns. Essentially the four columns above can only be present in that form once. I edited the question and hopefully that is more clear.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand you at all. You mean to have a unique value in those 4 columns like having a primary key form of those 4 columns. I think you must create a new column of calculated type that joins all those four columns in just one string. In addition, you must mark it as having unique values. In list views you can hide this new column to avoid users to see repeated values.

Comment: Okay, So I made a calculation but how do I enforce unique values in this calculation column there doesn't appear to be a option to enforce uniqueness.

Comment: Sorry, Robert, I was wrong with Calculated Columns, they can't be set as "Unique Values", here you have the [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee536168(v=office.14)) with the specifications for it. Anyway, I also found another similar or exact question as to the one you have with the correct answer, [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128677/unique-validation-on-calculated-column).

Comment: I think that here you have the two only solutions for having several columns as unique in a SharePoint list, client-side scripting or event receiver when adding and modifying. Apart from that, there is no out-of-the-box solution to reach that functionality.

Comment: Changed the answer with the information of these two last comments.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to write JS or use Event Receivers, Could you point me at any possible aides?

Comment: What do you mean with aides? expert people or companies that will help you accomplish that?

Comment: I meant a tutorial or any previous posts that cover using Event Receivers I'm having trouble understanding what exactly those are. Some articles I've read just list of features without really telling me what they are or how to utilize them.

Comment: As you are using SharePoint Online, you are able to customize your entry forms in an easy way. Just go to the list and click on the "customize" button to configure a custom form. Doing this way you are able to query the list for the values the user want to add and tell if those values exist or not. To wrap up, you can customize the entry forms and develop the unique values functionality in them instead of SharePoint itself.

Comment: Let me collect some links that shows you how you can do this with the different approaches commented here.

Comment: Here you have two links that will guide you on how to accomplish the form customization: [this first one](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form) shows you how to create a custom form with PowerApps and [this one](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Creating-Apps/How-to-check-if-an-item-exists-on-a-SharePoint-list-and-either/td-p/72024) can help you on how to check if the values of those columns exist in the list. Anyway, let me know if you need some more help and we can contact via email.

Comment: Hey so I'm interested in pursuing this topic still. My issue is I'm working from an older version of SharePoint (2013) and I do not have access to PowerApp or Flow. Only Designer and InfoPath. Is this still possible?

Comment: Having this scenario in mind, I think the best solution should be the creation of an item receiver before saving or updating the item to check all four column values. I don't know if there is an easy way or even a way of doing  this check with standard .net controls in a custom form using Designer. And, I cannot say anything about Infopath because I did nothing with it.